# How to sort data by using other values in python?

Tags: python, list

I have data in a text file --> 
p6;744951.1924;3553854.3858;246.8029
p1;745673.7331;35106063.9248;357.3721
p10;756311.8836;3546027.3642;922.0692
Now I want to sort the data according to first i.e p6,p1,p10.
I have done some code but I am not getting on how to sort. Please help

```
    id = []
    east = []
    north = []
    height = []
    sorted = []
    with open("coordinates.txt","r") as file:
        for line in file:
            data = line.split(";")
            id.append(data[0])
            east.append(round(float(data[1]),2))
            north.append(round(float(data[2]),2))
            height.append(round(float(data[3]),2))

    for x in id:
        # my code here

    print(id)
    print(east)
    print(north)
    print(height)
```

Comment: That is alrady in the order `p6`, `p1`,`p10`, Please explain what you are trying to achieve, you can add what the end result should look like

Comment: I want to sort it by id like first I have to print data of p1 then p2 and so on..@ThePyGuy

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
with open("coordinates.txt") as f:
    coordinates = [line.strip().split(";") for line in f.readlines()]

>>> sorted(coordinates, key=lambda x: int(x[0][1:]))
[['p1', '745673.7331', '35106063.9248', '357.3721'], 
 ['p6', '744951.1924', '3553854.3858', '246.8029'], 
 ['p10', '756311.8836', '3546027.3642', '922.0692']]
```

If you want to do it without lambda, you can save your data to a dictionary instead:

```
coordinates = dict()
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        i, n, e, h = line.strip().split(";")
        coordinates[int(i[1:])] = (float(n), float(e), float(h))

for key in sorted(coordinates):
    print(coordinates[key])
```

###### Output:

```
(745673.7331, 35106063.9248, 357.3721)
(744951.1924, 3553854.3858, 246.8029)
(756311.8836, 3546027.3642, 922.0692)
```

Comment: Can you please do it without using lamda as I am not very much confident with lamda.

Comment: @CodeWithFaraz - I added an alternate `dict` solution without `lambda`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
id, east, north, height = zip(*sorted(zip(id, east, north, height)))
```

Result:

```
>>> id
('p1', 'p10', 'p6')
>>> east
(745673.73, 756311.88, 744951.19)
>>> north
(35106063.92, 3546027.36, 3553854.38)
>>> height
(357.37, 922.06, 246.8)
```

If you're not happy with alphabetical order:

```
id, east, north, height = zip(*sorted(zip(id, east, north, height), key=lambda x: int(x[0][1:])))
```

Result:

```
>>> id
('p1', 'p6', 'p10')
>>> east
(745673.73, 744951.19, 756311.88)
>>> north
(35106063.92, 3553854.38, 3546027.36)
>>> height
(357.37, 246.8, 922.06)
```